# Dont lose the other choice with php filter

Tags: php, session, cookies, get

What is the best way to work to php with much filter?
I have `left.php` where I create all possible filters:

- color
- model
- size
- season
- type
  Ecc

I try with `$_get` to send the choice but I must think to remove anytime the same choice and not lose the other choice

If I choose model  X and color red and season winter, if I want change the color but not lose the other choice is hard...

The best solution? Work with SESSION?

Comment: When you're redisplaying the form, add the `selected` attribute to the options that correspond to the parameters that you received.